# Is it possible to find $a$ and $b$, if we just have the value of $q$ and $r$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In division theorem we have formula $a = qb + r$ and $0 < b > r$.

Then if we know the value of $a$ and $b$ then we can find $q$ and $r$. But is it possible if we just have the value of $q$ and $r$ can we find specific number of $a$ and $b$.

This is my answer I dont think we can't find it because we need $b$ to find $a$ but I can't prove it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have $q$ and $r$, you can choose any $b$ you want and *calculate* an appropriate $a$ simply by plugging into $a=qb+r$. Even if you require $b>r$, this lets you generate an unlimited number of different $(a,b)$ pairs that give rise to the same $(q,r)$.

Answer (score 1):

If this were true then

- $7$ divided by $4$ equals $1$ remains $3$
- $8$ divided by $5$ equals $1$ remains $3$

and since you claimed $(q,r)=(1,3)$ were enough to find $(a,b)$ then I would get $(7,4)=(8,5)$ and either $7=8$ or $5=4$ leads to $1=0$, contradiction.

So *"$1$ remains $3$"* is not a universal truth.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct; it is not possible to find $a$ give only $q$ and $r$. Instead, for any values of $q$ and $r$ such that $r<q$ you obtain a [residue class](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ResidueClass.html) of $q$. In other words, you obtain the set of integers such that when they are divided by $q$, the remainder is $r$. You can read more about residue classes in the above link or the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) on modular arithmetic, the field of math that investigates relationships between such residue classes.